# Final step in silverlight 2

Tags: silverlight-2.0, publishing, finalize

I have been working on multiple silverlight applications, but up to this point they have only been running in my system when I test them from Visual Studio. Now that I am getting ready to push it out I cannot figure out the steps to accomplishing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these two links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2008/03/18/configuring-a-web-server-to-host-silverlight-content.aspx
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/silverlight/

Basically you need to make sure your web host can run silverlight, then you deploy the XAP file (in your ClientBin folder)

On the page you want to reference the silverlight control, copy the sample silverlight object container and javascript references (silverlight.js) then just confirm the path to the xap file is correct.